# Compilation error in RouterEvent after migration from angular 15 to 16

Tags: filter, angular-router, angular16, angular-migration, angular-router-events

I was following the below document for migrating the angular 15 to 16

https://update.angular.io/?l=3&v=15.0-16.0

Executed `ng update @angular/core@16 @angular/cli@16` in project directory successfully, but getting one compilation issue in `RouterEvent`

```
     this._router.events
      .pipe(
        filter((evt: RouterEvent): boolean => {
          return evt instanceof NavigationEnd;
        }),
        take(1)
      )
      .subscribe((): void => {
      });
```

[image]

recreated same scenario in stack blitz

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-taobgv?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Could someone please help me to resolve this issue ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Found the solution :
https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/43124#issuecomment-2022533796